Trouble Verifying Purchase Status in Android App with Flutter and In-App Purchases
I am developing an app that features non-consumable in-app purchases. I've successfully implemented this on iOS, but I'm encountering issues with the Android version. I have set up an in-app product with the product ID "kaidoku" and designated my developer account as a test account. The purchase() function executes successfully, and when calling purchase() function for the second time, the message “You already own this item” is shown in the app, which shows that the purchase was made successfully. Therefore, it seems that in-app purchase is setup properly.
However, I face issues with verifying the purchase status. Upon initiating the app, the check() function is called, but it does not behave as expected. Here are the debug console outputs:
I/flutter (12879): Got into check() function
I/flutter (12879): Got out of listening

The check() function structure is as follows:
Future<void> check() async {
  final inapp = InAppPurchase.instance;
  print("Got into check() function");
  _subscription = inapp.purchaseStream.listen((data) async {
    print("Got into listening data");
  }, onDone: () {}, onError: (error) {});

  print("Got out of listening");
}

The debug message of "Got into listening data" is not shown, indicating that when processing _subscription = inapp.purchaseStream.listen((data) async { ... });, the code exits before entering the asynchronous function. This was further verified using step-over debugging in VS Code. Therefore, the purchase status is not checked as expected.
I suspect the listener is either not receiving data or there is a misconfiguration. Any insights on why this might be occurring and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';

String productId = 'kaidoku';

class InApp {
  final Set<String> _productIds = <String>{productId};
  final inapp = InAppPurchase.instance;
  late StreamSubscription _subscription;

  Future<void> check() async {
    final completer = Completer<void>();
    globals.purchaseCancel = false;
    globals.purchaseError = false;
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("Got into check() function");
    }
    _subscription = inapp.purchaseStream.listen((data) async {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Got into listening data");
      }
      if (data.isNotEmpty) {
        PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails =
            data.firstWhere((purchase) => purchase.productID == productId);

        switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
          case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
            if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
              await inapp.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
            }
            globals.purchased = true;
            if (!completer.isCompleted) {
              completer.complete();
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.error:
            globals.purchaseError = true;
            globals.purchaseErrorMessage = purchaseDetails.error.toString();
            if (!completer.isCompleted) {
              completer.complete();
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.pending:
            // Purchase is pending, waiting for update
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.restored:
            if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
              await inapp.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
            }
            globals.purchased = true;
            if (!completer.isCompleted) {
              completer.complete();
            }
            break;
          case PurchaseStatus.canceled:
            globals.purchaseCancel = true;
            await inapp.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
            if (!completer.isCompleted) {
              completer.complete();
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    }, onDone: () {
      globals.purchaseCancel = true;
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.complete();
      }
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      globals.purchaseError = true;
      globals.purchaseErrorMessage = 'Network connection error.';
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.complete();
      }
    });
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("Got out of listening");
    }
    return completer.future;
  }

  /// purchase
  Future<void> purchase() async {
    if (globals.purchased) {
      return;
    }
    //user will now buy the product
    List<ProductDetails> availableProducts = await _getAvailableProducts();
    if (availableProducts.isNotEmpty) {
      ProductDetails productDetails = availableProducts
          .firstWhere((productDetail) => productDetail.id == productId);
      final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
          PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
      await inapp.isAvailable();
      inapp.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    }
  }

  /// Restore purchase
  Future<void> restore() async {
    inapp.restorePurchases();
  }

  /// get products
  Future<List<ProductDetails>> _getAvailableProducts() async {
    await inapp.isAvailable();
    ProductDetailsResponse productDetailQueryResponse =
        await inapp.queryProductDetails(_productIds);
    return Future.value(productDetailQueryResponse.error == null
        ? productDetailQueryResponse.productDetails
        : <ProductDetails>[]);
  }
}


listen(...) is async, so Got into listening data will show after Got out of listening.
So what you see is expected. However, later you should see Got into listening data. If you don't, you should add some print statements onDone and onError to see what's going on.

I see. I don't get Got into listening data after Got out of listening. I added print statements at onDone and onError, So it seems to be waiting for the response of purchase stream.
I realized that the "release status" of "closed testing - alpha" is in review now. It may be the reason, so I will try again after the review is over.

So what do you get onDone and onError? Any clues about what's happening?

The debug print is not shown. Nothing happens after the message of "Got out of listening".

If you can buy products then the issue is not with the products set up. It should be something on you code. If you don't get anything on error nor on done, then it looks like the function is not executing or never ends. I can't help any further as I my Flutter skills are vary basic.
